# Object Oriented Aggregation/Association is not working

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, associations, aggregation

I am trying to call my class in another class, it calls the class but when i use class variable to use its method it doesn't show any. Kindly tell me where i am doing mistake.

```
class Course
{
    string mycourse;

    public Course(string course)
    {
        mycourse = course;

    }


    public void subjects()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("rEGISTERED"+ mycourse);

    }


}
```

***STUDENT CLASS***

```
class Students
{
    Course myCourse = new Course("English");


}
```

But In student class when i write myCourse. it doesn't show any methods of Course Class.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't show up in your IDE? Is this a compilation problem or IDE problem?

Comment: yes it doesnt show up in my IDE, and if i write this myCourse.subjects(); It gives me error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myCourse` here is a field

```
class Students
{
    Course myCourse = new Course("English");
    myCourse. ??? // nae, not gonna work
}
```

And you probably looking for a method, like

```
class Students
{
    public void AddCourse(string course)
    {
        Course myCourse = new Course(course);
        myCourse. //this is where you get IntelliSense
    }
}
```

And somewhere else

```
Student s = new Student();
s.AddCourse("English");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must place sections of code in either a method or constructor.

For instance, this should compile, now that `myCourse.subjects()` has been moved to the constructor:

```
class Students
{
    public Students()
    {
        Course myCourse = new Course("English");
        myCourse.subjects();
    }

}
```